# Mouse works fine but keyboard (not wireless) not responding to anything

Tags: keyboard

I read previous questions like mine and looked to see if keys were depressed and checked to make sure the mouse key was off in the system preferences.  The mouse works just fine but the keyboard seems to be dead.  I plugged in another keyboard and it responded identically.  Is it something in the Desktop itself?  Could I need a technician?  I have searched for answers on line and had no success.  Thanks!

Comment: Please specify what operating system you're using. Does it work before the OS loads? (i.e. in your BIOS setup?)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows or Mac?

What brand of Keyboard is it? Does the keyboard work on another computer?

Have you tried to update/install drivers?
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Update-a-driver-for-hardware-that-isnt-working-properly

Just trying to get to the bottom of the problem. Let us know here!

Comment: Of course, installing drivers could be a bit of a problem.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The mouse works, but not the keyboard. You could click through the process...

Answer (score 0):

Did you wait 5 minutes for the Operating System to load the drivers? New keyboards often seem to be broken while this is happening. I suspect that the old keyboard is dead and your new keyboard ran into this issue. Also, like Buildakicker says, does this keyboard work on another computer?